# Выборка двух полей одной таблицы по id в другой

Tags: sql

Имеется 2 поля в первой таблице, значения которых - id записей во второй таблице. В первой таблице в одной записи значения этих полей не могут быть одинаковыми. Как я могу объединить так, чтобы получая значение нужного поля по id во второй таблице, оно сопоставилось с соответствующим столбцом в первой таблице?
Конечно хотелось бы узнать оптимальный вариант, но пока нет никаких идей, как это можно сделать, и буду рад любому варианту.
Таблички условно:
table1

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | field1| field2|
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     2 |
|  2 |     1 |     3 |
|  3 |     2 |     4 |
|  4 |     3 |     2 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

table2

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | name            |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | name1           |
|  2 | name2           |
|  3 | name3           |
|  4 | name4           |
+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Вам нужно ознакомиться с концепцией внешних ключей (Foreign keys)  и синтаксисом JOIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.id,
       t2.name,
       t3.name 
from   table1 t1 
left   join table2 t2
on     t1.field1 = t2.id
left   join table2 t3
on     t1.field2 = t3.id
```